# What are the conditional operators we can use in react js under render method?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to perform some logic using switch or for or if loop .But i cannot use 
anyone of this in render method.right now i am using ternary operator.Is there any other operators which we can access in the render method?

Comment: Do not use a `for` loop or anything complicated. Anything in JSX is best left purely functional and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline function. 
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/viviancpy/7v9th3Lj/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>




var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        {(() => {
        switch (this.props.name) {
          case "World":   return (<div>Oh this is a Hello World</div>);
          default:       return (<div>Good Morning</div>);
        }
      })()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Adding logic this way is a great way to disaster.

Comment: @Dariusz do you have any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the examples on https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html.

One option is to use logic outside of the JSX and store the sub-components in variables you can inject into the JSX later.

Example (from the link above):

```
var loginButton;
if (loggedIn) {
  loginButton = <LogoutButton />;
} else {
  loginButton = <LoginButton />;
}

return (
  <nav>
    <Home />
    {loginButton}
  </nav>
);
```